# The football trial

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

A football (or soccer) team is holding trials. Unfortunately the team has only one goal available.

The coach splits the ten players into two teams. There are 4 defenders.

The goalkeeper will play for the defending team.

One team must attack.

Team A are attacking and Team B are defending. After a go they will swap round so A are defending and B are attacking.

> Who has the advantage, Team A or Team B?

Comment: "*...the tea has only one goal...*" ... and that is to be poured and drunk!

Comment: @feelinferrety :P

Comment: But who's the quarterback?

Comment: @IanMaconald are you thinking american football? This is english football/soccer

Comment: The puzzle here seems to be to correctly guess the meaning of a very ambiguous setup. In particular, the answer which is marked as correct assumes that team A consists of the midfielders and attackers and team B consists of the defenders, but there's nothing in the question which says that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think:

> Team A 
>  
>  Team A starts with 5 outfield attacking players to the 4 defenders and goalie of team B. Now when the teams swap team B have 4 outfield players attacking to the 5 defenders and a goalie of team A, leaving them in a 6vs4 scenario.

Comment: Correct! That was quick